# How to stop Electron Window from going Fullscreen when using the Youtube fullscreen button inside of a BrowserView or Webview

Tags: javascript, electron

I am  making an application that has a BrowserWindow or Webview that allows the user to browse the internet. When using Youtube, if you click the fullscreen button, my entire Electron applications goes fullscreen. Not the video, but my entire application, and then to exit fullscreen I have to use Youtube's fullscreen button. Here is an image of what it looks like:

[image: tag]

In this image my entire application is in fullscreen mode. Is there a way to stop this from happening? I like that the BrowserView itself has the Youtube video in fullscreen, but I do not like that my entire application becomes fullscreen. This happens with all videos with fullscreen buttons, such as Twitch.

-Thank you

edit: I found a potential temporary fix. If I set the BrowserWindow options "fullscreenable" to false so fullscreenable: false, it prevents videos in BrowserView from bein able to make my applications fullscreen while still filling up the BrowserView. I am still interested in if there is another way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

This is old I know but I have the same issue.
Unfortunately, the option you found is the most straight-forward.

The issue with setting `fullscreen: false`, is that you lose the ability to go to full screen when you actually want to via the window control.

There are hooks that differentiate between full screen being invoked by the window vs. HTML, but they are after the fact and not cancel-able (`enter-html-full-screen` and `enter-full-screen`).

The option I am using is this:

```
  win.on('enter-html-full-screen', function () {
    if (win.isFullScreen()) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        win.setFullScreen(false)
        win.maximize()
      }, 1000)
    }
  })
```

You have to wait for the window to complete the move to full screen hence the timeout. If you log out `isFullScreen`, you will see it invoked immediately, but then promptly get a log saying the window is not in full screen when you try to set it to false without the timeout.

This solution maximises the window, which may not be desired. You could instead restore the window the previous dimensions, but then you get a rubber-band effect.

Another option might be to toggle the window to be `fullScreen: true` when you use the window control and then toggle it back off via IPC, but I can't find a straight-forward way to do that. We need a `pre-enter-html-fullscreen` we can cancel.